# Every second API request takes a long time when I send request through browser. With postman request take the fixed amount of time

Tags: laravel, api, google-chrome, postman

I use laravel (7 or 8 version no difference), php 7.4 (opcache enabled). axios/fetch(empty request) no difference. browser edge/chrome no difference.

[image: Chrome network log]

What's interesting when server take (long-time) request there is no "Closing" message
[image: php server log]

Fast request
[image]

Postman: all OK!
[image: With postman all OK!]